# Apache NiFi: hot folder mechanism

Tags: apache-nifi

Could anyone explain to me what principle/approach/mechanism is being used for hot-folder functionality in NiFi?

Which maven sub-project and/or files should I examine to understand that?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by hot-folder functionality? If you mean how NiFi "notices" that there are new data files in a directory, check out List processors such as the [ListFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html) processor. They subclass [AbstractListProcessor](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/AbstractListProcessor.java) which takes care of looking for files they haven't seen before and keeping track of which they have seen.

If you mean hot-folders for dynamically loading processors/modules/NARs, that does not exist at this time but there is a [Feature Proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Extension+Repositories+%28aka+Extension+Registry%29+for+Dynamically-loaded+Extensions#ExtensionRepositories(akaExtensionRegistry)forDynamically-loadedExtensions-5.UseCases) to add such a capability.

Comment: Thanks mattyb, I meant the first variant. I'll check ListFile and AbstractListProcessor.